# How to retrieve a custom section from an app.config in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 library project, inside there's an App.config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="NewDocumentMetadata" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </configSections>
    <NewDocumentMetadata>
        <add key="Type" value="principal"/>
        <add key="IsActive" value="true"/>
    </NewDocumentMetadata>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Entity" value="9"/>
        <add key="Flux" value="pdf"/>
    </appSettings>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <!-- [...] -->
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, I have some standard settings, but also a custom section. I have no problems with the settings, but when I retrieve the section, it works, but there I'm stuck, when I try to cast it to `NameValueCollection` or `AppSettingsSection` it gives me a `null` value, I'm stuck with a `ConfigurationOption` object I am not able to work with.

```
        var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        flux = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["Flux"].Value; //Works
        entity = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["Entity"].Value; //Works

        var metadataSection = appConfig.GetSection("NewDocumentMetadata"); //What do I do with this boy?
```

I need to retrieve the settings within the `NewDocumentMetadata` section, how to proceed?

Comment: There is no value for the "NewDocumentMetadata"  It is just a section.  You need to add innertext with a value.

Comment: @jdweng I am declaring the section properties just after the `configSections` tag, am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: You have cast it with   NameValueCollection.            
 var metadataSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("NewDocumentMetadata") as

Comment: You are just declaring a section and then you are not adding any properties.  It is like putting a section for a person first name and then forgetting to add the name like John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the problem was with this line :

```
<section name="NewDocumentMetadata"        
         type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
```

I changed the type and went for this :

```
<section name="NewDocumentMetadata"  
         type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

Now I just have to do this kind of code to retrieve the values I want:

```
var metadataSection = (AppSettingsSection)appConfig.GetSection("NewDocumentMetadata");

foreach (var key in metadataSection.Settings.AllKeys)
{
    string value = metadataSection.Settings[key].Value;
}
```

Comment: Another issue for anyone struggling is that the appSettings section must be BELOW all custom configuration sections.  E.g.:

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="QA" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
   </configSections>
  <QA>
    <add key="selectpayment_host" value="qa url" />
  </QA>
  <PE>
    <add key="selectpayment_host" value="pe url" />
  </PE>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="environment" value="qa" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```
var metadataSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("NewDocumentMetadata") as NameValueCollection;

// Get all the value foreach key
foreach(var key in metadataSection.AllKeys)
{
string value = metadataSection.GetValues(key).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Comment: I get a compilation error with the casting. `Cannot convert type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion`. Am I using the wrong `NameValueCollection` class?

Comment: I made a mistake sorry --' replace `appConfig` by `ConfigurationManager` it should work

Comment: Oh, thanks. This actually compiles but since I'm generating a dll that is used on other projects, I actually need to go through this line `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` to read the configurations from the `x.dll.config` file and not from another `app.config` file. So this method of accessing the section only returns null sinon `ConfigurationManager` only tries to access a local `app.config`. I don't know if I'm clear enough